# How do I change the colour palette in the dabest_plot function in dabestr_2023.9.12

Tags: r, ggplot2, colors, palette

Just wanting to add a custom palette to this visualization. I have tried adding it manually using palette = c("colour1", "colour2",...) and using custom_palette. Nothing is working. Is there a way to extract this data and run it in ggplot2?

Here is the code I am working with:
#Multi-group analysis in dabestr

```
multi_groups <- load(data, x = Treatment, y = Total_CO2,
idx = list(
c("GB-L", "LDPE-L"),
c("GB-H", "LDPE-H"),
c("GF-L", "PA-L"),
c("GF-H", "PA-H") ))

print(multi_groups)

multi_groups.mean_diff <- mean_diff(multi_groups)
print(multi_groups.mean_diff)
multi_groups.mean_diff
```

#Plots

```
dabest_plot(multi_groups.mean_diff) <--- THIS IS WHERE I WANT TO CHANGE THE COLOUR PALETTE
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5hjP6.png)

```
dabest_plot(multi_groups.mean_diff, palette = c("colour1", "colour2"... etc) - did not change the colours
```

Comment: According to the documentation, the argument `custom_palette` is used. This can be any one of npg, aaas, nejm, lancet, jama, jco, ucscgb, d3, locuszoom, igv, cosmic, uchicago, brewer, ordinal, viridis_d. The default is "d3"

Answer (score 1):

If you look at the documentation for `?dabest_plot`, you will see that it only describes two named arguments, neither of which control the color, but the function also allows extra arguments to be passed via `...`.

> `...` Adjustment parameters to control and adjust the appearance of the plot. (list of all possible adjustment parameters can be found under plot_kwargs)

We therefore need to look up the documents for `?plot_kwargs` to find out how to control the color palette. Here we find that there is an argument called `custom_palette`:

> `custom_palette` Default "d3". String. The following palettes are available for use: npg, aaas, nejm, lancet, jama, jco, ucscgb, d3, locuszoom, igv, cosmic, uchicago, brewer, ordinal, viridis_d.

Essentially, these are the palettes you are stuck with. Although the final object produced by the `dabest_plot` function is a ggplot object, it is actually a `cowplot` type ggplot, meaning one cannot simply add new color and fill scales to it.

To be fair, there are several palettes to choose from, all of which give quite a professional look.

Here's an example:

```r
library(dabestr)

dabest_obj <- load(non_proportional_data,
                   x = Group, y = Measurement,
                   idx = c("Control 1", "Test 1", "Test 2", "Test 3"))

dabest_obj.mean_diff <- mean_diff(dabest_obj)

dabest_plot(dabest_obj.mean_diff, TRUE)
```

[image]

And here with a different palette:

```r
dabest_plot(dabest_obj.mean_diff, TRUE, custom_palette = "igv")
```

[image]

From looking at the code of the package, it doesn't look as though it would be terribly difficult to add in a fully customizable palette, but it seems that [this is not a priority](https://github.com/ACCLAB/dabestr/issues/160) for the authors right now.

Comment: Thank you for your detailed answer! 
Ioo bad we cant fully customize colours